# Service account Google oAuth: file_get_contents .p12 failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: google-oauth, google-api-php-client, file-not-found

I am trying to run Google oAuth Service Account by specifying `keyfilelocation` as below:

```
$client_id = 'xccsssds-ib5c5qmr7n34aifss95ue7qouplh7v3r.apps.googleusercontent.com'; //Client ID
$service_account_name = 'sdfdsfsxxxxxxxxxsdfdsf-ib5c5qmr7n34aifss95ue7qouplh7v3r@developer.gserviceaccount.com'; //Email Address
$key_file_location = 'My Cloud Project-e2a5b459dfd9.p12'; //key.p12
```

But my server is throwing error like:

```
file_get_contents(My Cloud Project-e2a5b459dfd9.p12): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in XXXXXXXXXX
Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Unable to parse the p12 file. Is this a .p12 file? Is the password correct? OpenSSL error: '
```

Path of the `p12` file correct and gave file permissions correctly  but it was throwing this error.

Comment: can you include your full file_get_contents line.   As the error message states it cant find the file.  as a test try putting it in the same dir as the file and see if it works.

Comment: p12 file was in same directory as this service page is there, and more over file_get_contents was reading all other files, except this file, and my php version is 5.4 , is that the any problem.

Comment: here is a working example using the Calendar API.  http://www.daimto.com/google-calendar-api-with-php-service-account/

Comment: thanks, i saw that link, the same i followed but my server is not reading this p12 file, i checked that using is_readable function, it returns false, may be problem with my server

Comment: linux or windows? rename the file crap.p12 could it be the spaces in the name causing a problem?

Comment: linux, hostgator, may be no permission to read certificates in this server, contacting support.

Comment: what are the permissions set to on the file? php needs to be able to read it and php normally runs as some weird user NOBODY if I remember.